# Calling gnuplot from python

Tags: python, gnuplot

I've a python script that after some computing will generate two data files formatted as gnuplot input.

How do I 'call' gnuplot from python ?

I want to send the following python string as input to gnuplot:

```
"plot '%s' with lines, '%s' with points;" % (eout,nout)
```

where '*eout*' and '*nout*' are the two filenames.

PS:
I **prefer** not to use additional python modules (eg. gnuplot-py), only the standard API.

Thank You

Comment: You want to call gnuplot using API (which is in C, so you would have to write some glue code like the one in gnuplot-py) or just execute "gnuplot" in shell?

Comment: Just execute gnuplot in shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple approach might be to just write a third file containing your gnuplot commands and then tell Python to execute gnuplot with that file. Say you write

```
"plot '%s' with lines, '%s' with points;" % (eout,nout)
```

to a file called tmp.gp. Then you can use

```
from os import system, remove
system('gnuplot -persist tmp.gp')
remove('tmp.gp')
```

Comment: Thanks, this hack eventually worked.
One mention: system('gnuplot -persist tmp.gp') in order to persist the windows after the script finishes.

Answer (score 24):

The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module lets you call other programs:

```
import subprocess
plot = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
plot.communicate("plot '%s' with lines, '%s' with points;" % (eout,nout))
```

Comment: After reading your example, I've written a similar function, unfortunately, no results.
(POpen = Popen, a typo I believe, but this wasn't the problem)

Comment: Yes, POpen was a typo. Aside from that, maybe you need to specify the full path to gnuplot or add the '-persist' switch you mention in another comment. You can also check `plot.returncode` for errors.

Comment: For someone who receives `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'”` error: [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989808/subprocess-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-python-2)

Answer (score 18):

Subprocess is explained very clearly on Doug Hellemann's
[Python Module of the Week](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/)

This works well:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot','-p'], 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
proc.stdin.write('set xrange [0:10]; set yrange [-2:2]\n')
proc.stdin.write('plot sin(x)\n')
proc.stdin.write('quit\n') #close the gnuplot window
proc.stdin.flush()
```

One could also use 'communicate' but the plot window closes immediately unless a gnuplot pause command is used

```
proc.communicate("""
set xrange [0:10]; set yrange [-2:2]
plot sin(x)
pause 4
""")
```

Comment: Use `shell=False` and gnuplot `--persist` if you just want to show the window, and not have Python close it...

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to do something similar, but additionally I wanted to feed data from within python and output the graph *file* as a variable (so neither the data nor the graph are actual files). This is what I came up with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
from sys import stdout, stderr
from os import linesep as nl

def gnuplot_ExecuteCommands(commands, data):
    args = ["gnuplot", "-e", (";".join([str(c) for c in commands]))]
    program = subprocess.Popen(\
        args, \
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, \
        )
    for line in data:
        program.stdin.write(str(line)+nl)
    return program

def gnuplot_GifTest():
    commands = [\
        "set datafile separator ','",\
        "set terminal gif",\
        "set output",\
        "plot '-' using 1:2 with linespoints, '' using 1:2 with linespoints",\
        ]
    data = [\
        "1,1",\
        "2,2",\
        "3,5",\
        "4,2",\
        "5,1",\
        "e",\
        "1,5",\
        "2,4",\
        "3,1",\
        "4,4",\
        "5,5",\
        "e",\
        ]
    return (commands, data)

if __name__=="__main__":
    (commands, data) = gnuplot_GifTest()
    plotProg = gnuplot_ExecuteCommands(commands, data)
    (out, err) = (plotProg.stdout, plotProg.stderr)
    stdout.write(out.read())
```

That script dumps the graph to stdout as the last step in **main**. The equivalent command line (where the graph is piped to 'out.gif') would be:

```
gnuplot -e "set datafile separator ','; set terminal gif; set output; plot '-' using 1:2 with linespoints, '' using 1:2 with linespoints" > out.gif
1,1
2,2
3,5
4,2
5,1
e
1,5
2,4
3,1
4,4
5,5
e
```

Answer (score 4):

I went with Ben's suggestion as I was computing charts from a celery job and found that it would lockup when reading from stdout. I redesigned it like so using StringIO to create the file destined for stdin and subprocess.communicate to get the result immediately via stdout, no read required.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from StringIO import StringIO                                            
from os import linesep as nl

def gnuplot(commands, data):                                                    
    """ drive gnuplot, expects lists, returns stdout as string """              

    dfile = StringIO()                                                          
    for line in data:                                                           
        dfile.write(str(line) + nl)                                             

    args = ["gnuplot", "-e", (";".join([str(c) for c in commands]))]            
    p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)                       

    dfile.seek(0)                                                               
    return p.communicate(dfile.read())[0]   

def gnuplot_GifTest():
    commands = [\
        "set datafile separator ','",\
        "set terminal gif",\
        "set output",\
        "plot '-' using 1:2 with linespoints, '' using 1:2 with linespoints",\
        ]
    data = [\
        "1,1",\
        "2,2",\
        "3,5",\
        "4,2",\
        "5,1",\
        "e",\
        "1,5",\
        "2,4",\
        "3,1",\
        "4,4",\
        "5,5",\
        "e",\
        ]
    return (commands, data)

if __name__=="__main__":
    (commands, data) = gnuplot_GifTest()
    print gnuplot(commands, data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a class that provides an interface to wgnuplot.exe:

```
from ctypes import *
import time
import sys
import os

#
# some win32 constants
#
WM_CHAR     = 0X0102
WM_CLOSE    = 16
SW_HIDE     = 0
STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1

WORD    = c_ushort
DWORD   = c_ulong
LPBYTE  = POINTER(c_ubyte)
LPTSTR  = POINTER(c_char) 
HANDLE  = c_void_p

class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cb",DWORD),
        ("lpReserved",LPTSTR), 
        ("lpDesktop", LPTSTR),
        ("lpTitle", LPTSTR),
        ("dwX", DWORD),
        ("dwY", DWORD),
        ("dwXSize", DWORD),
        ("dwYSize", DWORD),
        ("dwXCountChars", DWORD),
        ("dwYCountChars", DWORD),
        ("dwFillAttribute", DWORD),
        ("dwFlags", DWORD),
        ("wShowWindow", WORD),
        ("cbReserved2", WORD),
        ("lpReserved2", LPBYTE),
        ("hStdInput", HANDLE),
        ("hStdOutput", HANDLE),
        ("hStdError", HANDLE),]

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("hProcess", HANDLE),
        ("hThread", HANDLE),
        ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
        ("dwThreadId", DWORD),]

#
# Gnuplot
#
class Gnuplot:
    #
    # __init__
    #
    def __init__(self, path_to_exe):
        # open gnuplot
        self.launch(path_to_exe)
        # wait till it's ready
        if(windll.user32.WaitForInputIdle(self.hProcess, 1000)):
            print "Error: Gnuplot timeout!"
            sys.exit(1)
        # get window handles
        self.hwndParent = windll.user32.FindWindowA(None, 'gnuplot')
        self.hwndText = windll.user32.FindWindowExA(self.hwndParent, None, 'wgnuplot_text', None)



    #
    # __del__
    #
    def __del__(self):
        windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(self.hProcess);
        windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(self.hThread);
        windll.user32.PostMessageA(self.hwndParent, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)


    #
    # launch
    #
    def launch(self, path_to_exe):
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()

        startupinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE

        if windll.kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe, None, None, None, False, 0, None, None, byref(startupinfo), byref(process_information)):
            self.hProcess = process_information.hProcess
            self.hThread = process_information.hThread
        else:
            print "Error: Create Process - Error code: ", windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
            sys.exit(1)



    #
    # execute
    #
    def execute(self, script, file_path):
        # make sure file doesn't exist
        try: os.unlink(file_path)
        except: pass

        # send script to gnuplot window
        for c in script: windll.user32.PostMessageA(self.hwndText, WM_CHAR, ord(c), 1L)

        # wait till gnuplot generates the chart
        while( not (os.path.exists(file_path) and (os.path.getsize(file_path) > 0))): time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late, but since it took me some time to make it work, maybe it's worth putting a note. The programs are working with Python 3.3.2 on Windows.

Notice that bytes are used everywhere, not strings (e.g. b"plot x", not simply "plot x"), but in case it's a problem, simply do something like:

```
"plot x".encode("ascii")
```

First solution: use *communicate* to send everything, and  close when it's done. One must not forget *pause*, or the window is closed at once. However, it's not a problem if gnuplot is used to store images in files.

```
from subprocess import *
path = "C:\\app\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot"
p = Popen([path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p.communicate(b"splot x*y\npause 4\n")
```

Second solution: send commands one after another, using stdin.write(...). But, **don't forget flush**! (this is what I didn't get right at first) And use *terminate* to close the connection and gnuplot when the job is done.

```
from subprocess import *
path = "C:\\app\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot"
p = Popen([path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

p.stdin.write(b"splot x*y\n")
p.stdin.flush()
...
p.stdin.write(b"plot x,x*x\n")
p.stdin.flush()
...
p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example which extends some of the previous answers. This solution **requires Gnuplot 5.1** because it uses datablocks. For more information on datablocks, execute `help datablocks` in gnuplot.
The problem with some of the previous approaches is that `plot '-'` instantly consumes the data that immediately follows the plot command. It is not possible to reuse the same data in a subsequent plot command. datablocks can be used to alleviate this issue. Using datablocks we can mimic multiple datafiles. For instance, you may want to plot a graph using data from two data files, e.g. `plot "myData.dat" using 1:2 with linespoints, '' using 1:3 with linespoints, "myData2.dat" using 1:2 with linespoints`. We could feed this data directly to gnuplot without the need to create actual data files.

```
import sys, subprocess
from os import linesep as nl
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def gnuplot(commands, data):                                                    
  """ drive gnuplot, expects lists, returns stdout as string """  
  script= nl.join(data)+nl.join(commands)+nl
  print script
  args = ["gnuplot", "-p"]
  p = Popen(args, shell=False, stdin=PIPE)                       
  return p.communicate(script)[0]  

def buildGraph():
  commands = [\
      "set datafile separator ','",\
      "plot '$data1' using 1:2 with linespoints, '' using 1:3 with linespoints, '$data2' using 1:2 with linespoints",\
      ]
  data = [\
      "$data1 << EOD",\
      "1,30,12",\
      "2,40,15",\
      "3,35,20",\
      "4,60,21",\
      "5,50,30",\
      "EOD",\
      "$data2 << EOD",\
      "1,20",\
      "2,40",\
      "3,40",\
      "4,50",\
      "5,60",\
      "EOD",\
      ]

  return (commands, data)  


def main(args):
  (commands, data) = buildGraph()
  print gnuplot(commands, data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

This method is a bit more versatile than `plot '-'` as it makes it easier to reuse the same data multiple times, including on the same plot command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33064402/895245
Notice that this approach requires that the data is fed to *gnuplot* before the plot commands!

Also, I did not use IOString as @ppetraki did, since apparently this is slower than a simple list joiner: https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Comment: The values in data must be written without comas. Columns are separated by spaces, as reported in the gnuplot help. Also in python3 you must encode() the string scripts: `return p.communicate(script.encode('utf-8'))[0]`

Comment: @terencehill That's not true: you can use any separator, as long as you specify the command `set datafile separator ','`, see my example above.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the command and missed the line referring to the separator.