# How to plot a data cube in python

Tags: python, plot, cube

I was wondering if there's a way to plot a data cube in Python. I mean I have three coordinate for every point

```
x=part.points[:,0]
y=part.points[:,1]
z=part.points[:,2]
```

And for every point I have a scalar field t(x,y,z)

I would like to plot a 3D data cube showing the position of the point and for every point a color which is proportional to the scalar field t in that point.

I tried with histogramdd but it didn't work.

Comment: Google: http://old.nabble.com/4D-Scatter-Plot-td31978523.html

Comment: http://pyx.sourceforge.net/examples/3dgraphs/color.html - this might work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).
Here you have a working example (that moves!):

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

mypoints = []
for _ in range(100):
    mypoints.append([random.random(),    #x
                    random.random(),     #y
                    random.random(),     #z
                    random.randint(10,100)]) #scalar

data = zip(*mypoints)           # use list(zip(*mypoints)) with py3k  

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(data[0], data[1], data[2], c=data[3])
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

You probably have to customize the relation of your scalar values with the corresponding colors.
Matplotlib has a very nice look but it can be slow drawing and moving these 3D drawings when you have many points. In these cases I used to use [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) controlled by [gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/). Gnuplot can also be used directly as a subprocess as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161932/calling-gnuplot-from-python) and [here](http://linuxgazette.net/114/andreasen.html).

Comment: thanks! Can I ask you also how to add the zlabel, apart from the obvious x and y labels? I tried with pyploy.zlabel("my_label") but it didn't work. Moreover, if the points are too much this code get stuck. How can I apply them a gaussian filter to smooth them and still have a nice 3D plot?

Comment: Another thing. How can I add a title to the plot and a colorbar show the legend for the colors?

Comment: ax.set_zlabel('Z'). ax.set_title('Mi Title'). You can experiment for the others or maybe to ask SO.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Dots](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_93.html#Dots-sample) plot, produced by [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/). It is GPL plotting library. Add it don't need many memory if you save in bitmap format (PNG, JPEG, GIF and so on).