# How can I smooth a set of 3D points?

Tags: python, plot

this question is an extension of my previous question that you can find here:

[How to plot a data cube in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870922/how-to-plot-a-data-cube-in-python)

The thing is that I have a 3D plot of point but if I follow the method of my previous question I could get an overflow error when I have too many points to plot. 
I have to plot millions of points so I need to smooth the 3D distribution, otherwise it takes a huge amount of time to make the plot and I could also get memory errors.

I was thinking that maybe I can convolve the distribution with a Gaussian kernel, but I don't know if it's the best option. Moreover, I am not able to do it yet.

Comment: I think the answer depends upon which information you consider the most important. There are different options, depending on which information you are more willing to lose.

Comment: I am interested on the spatial distribution of this point, on average.

Comment: First: if you have millions of points, will you ever be able to see past the edges of your cube? In other words: is a 3d visualization the best idea or might you be better off making 2d slices (for example?. Furhermore: you might construct a 3d array, filling every cell with the mean or median of the points within that cell.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's what I did for a 2D visualization, but I would like to see the data cube.

Comment: Could you give an example of how your preferred solution should look? Perhaps a pen&paper sketch of your ideal graph. Or is your question merely how you can reduce the number of points while losing minimal information? Then a sample of your data would help: are the points clustered or evenly spread? Are the function values at (x,y,z) randomly varying or smoothly distributed? Etcetera, etcetera.

Comment: No, my point are not evenly spread. I would like to have something like this http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/files/2007/darkmatter_blobs.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered in original question, the [Dots](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_93.html#Dots-sample) plot is good for you. It is produced by [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) -- GPL plotting library. Add it don't need many memory if you save in bitmap format (PNG, JPEG, GIF and so on).

However, there are another option for smoothing itself:
(i) make histogram of point distribution (i.e. average points values or colors inside some cell) -- in frame MathGL you can use Hist() function even for points in 3D space; or
(ii) using standard smoothing functions (like mglData::Smooth() in MathGL), but here you need to use regular arrays, i.e. as {x[i,j,k], y[i,j,k], z[i,j,k], c[i,j,k]}.

Both variant will give you regular arrays which can be plotted by a set of different ways -- see these [samples](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/en/3d_plots.html).