# Gnuplot - data points in script

Tags: gnuplot

I have C++ program that now generates two files:

- data file (with columns of data)
- gnuplot script (to set ranges and labels properly)

So, for plot I need to have two files which are related to each other.

Is there any possibility, to pack it all to one file? I mean: to put data points coordinates inside gnuplot script?

I am using gnuplot 4.4.

Comment: also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/10397750/2001017

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can put datapoints inside your gnuplot script. The simplest example would be

```
plot "-" with lines, "-" with lines
1 1
2 2
3 3
e
1 3
2 2
3 1
```

Comment: I would mention that for more information you can look for 'special-filenames' in the gnuplot documentation: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf