# How to input coordinates within the splot function for ftriangles in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add a triangle between three points in my gnuplot.

I found this code:

```
set pm3d ftriangles
splot 'x.txt' w pm3d notitle
```

whereby x.txt contains for instance:

```
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
```

I would like to be able to do embed all of the code in 1 script without having the extra text file, so just together with the splot command. Is this possible? I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
set pm3d ftriangles
splot w pm3d notitle
0 0 1
e
1 1 0
e
1 0 1
e
```

Sorry for missing some basics in gnuplot...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a not-so-elegant small shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > x.txt << EOF
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
EOF

gnuplot << GNUPLOT

set pm3d ftriangles
splot 'x.txt' w pm3d notitle

GNUPLOT

rm x.txt
```

Comment: The thing is, I already have a .plt script which draws a complicated 3d plot and I want to add this to the existing script (without having to have a second file x.txt)

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722048/gnuplot-data-points-in-script) should work:

```
splot '-' w pm3d notitle
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
e
```