# Is there any python module to plot 2d cartesian coordinate in text mode?

Tags: python, text, module, plot

matplotlib seems only can plot in GUI or output picture/ps format like files. Is there any module to plot and output text mode figures?
eg.

```
^
|          o    
|  o           o   o
|      o   
|                      o
|                          o
|    
+------------------------------>
0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried [ASCII-Plotter](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ASCII-Plotter/1.0)?

Alternatively you can call gnuplot from your python script. See [Command-line Unix ASCII-based charting / plotting tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123378/command-line-unix-ascii-based-charting-plotting-tool) and [Calling gnuplot from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161932/calling-gnuplot-from-python).