# How to read a user keyboard input during a Gnuplot script execution?

Tags: input, gnuplot, stdin

How can I ask the user to enter a value during the execution of a GnuPlot script?

I would like to use stdin to initialize some plotting parameters.

I have try to call :
   a=system("read")
and 
  pause mouse keypressed

Without sucess.

Any help welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on Linux. Your shell command must write something to stdout which gnuplot can read from stdin. Something like this should work:

```
print "Pleaser enter a number: " 
a = system("read a; echo $a")

plot a*sin(x)
pause mouse close
```

Would it be an alternative to write a script in [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044585/opening-gnuplot-using-a-bash-script-file-and-then-plotting-a-csv-file), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161932/calling-gnuplot-from-python), ... which reads user input and calls gnuplot afterwards? (The links are my first google results, I have mainly read the title.)